# append values in a list without sorting python, keeping the appending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am producing a list of list by this code, it is just a condition for a column of a dataframe named lvl or "Level", then append the index of this condition values, so the problem that i got is that the order of appending is important to me,

`for i in range(1,int(24-lvl)):
                j=list2[(list2.lvl==(lvl+i))]
                jj=[]
                jj.append(j.index)
print itertools.chain(jj)`

well for example, the answer should be:
`[0,100,110,500,501,550,555,89,120,114]`
but i get the same list but sorted
`[0,89,100,110,114,120,500,501,550,555]`

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.chain` works for me. You need to unpack the list before passing it to `chain` method.

```
>>> l = [[1,5],[10,2],[6,9,3]]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*l))
[1, 5, 10, 2, 6, 9, 3]
```

Comment: Or, better, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)`.

Comment: check this out
http://imgur.com/1apSyZw
it still results as an ordered list
this are the original values that i am working

Comment: You use Int64Index maybe you should add some tags like panda ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [[1,5],[10,2],[6,9,3]]
>>> l_out = [item for sub_l in l for item in sub_l]
>>> l_out
[1, 5, 10, 2, 6, 9, 3]
```

Comment: check this out imgur.com/1apSyZw it still results as an ordered list this are the original values that i am working

Comment: Why the down vote?..Express the cause behind it so I can fix my answer...

Comment: i didnt downvote bro :(
I found out what was the problem,